# How to view a blocked Facebook user's full profile?

Tags: facebook, facebook-profile

Six months ago, a user blocked me in Facebook. Now I want to see his/her full profile.

Is there any method that I can use to see his/her full profile?

Comment: That would kind of defeat the purpose of a block, no?

Answer (score 3):

Once you are blocked on Facebook you are blocked from seeing that person's profile and anything about that person while you are logged into the account that is blocked.

However, if you create a second account or have a second account to log into then you can see that person's profile with the second account that is not blocked. As far as the full profile you would have to more than likely become friends with that person depending on the privacy settings that person has set for his/her account.

Comment: as a developer we cant hack using any code?

Comment: I wouldn't advise attempting to hack Facebook.

Comment: but is there any method for hack?